# installing libsvm on Mac (OSX 10.9.2)

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I have tried to install the libsvm package with

```
mex -setup
```

(since "make" resulted in an error). This was followed by one choice for a compiler, so I chose "1".
Afterwards I typed in "make" got the following error though:

```
xcrun: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7'
libsvmread.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.

    mex: compile of ' "libsvmread.c"' failed.

If make.m fails, please check README about detailed instructions.
```

What can I do?

Comment: Check your header file search path.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using and which OS X?

Comment: matlab 2013b, OS see title: 10.9.2

Answer (score 1):

I think the following answer from the matlab support might be helpful (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103904-can-i-use-xcode-5-as-my-c-or-c-compiler-in-matlab-8-1-r2013a-or-matlab-8-2-r2013b):

> The Mac OS X 10.7 SDK, available in Xcode 4.1 through 4.6, is used by
>   MEX and related capabilities. This SDK is no longer available in Xcode
>   5, resulting in errors similar to the following when compiling:
>
> xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located.
>
> xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or
>   in PATH
>
> The simplest solution is to avoid updating Xcode to version 5 if you
>   are using R2013a or R2013b. If you need Xcode 5, or you have already
>   irreversibly upgraded to it, you can update MEX to use the 10.8 SDK:
>
> 1. In the MATLAB Command Window, execute the following commands:
>
> cd(matlabroot)
>
> cd bin
>
> edit mexopts.sh
>
> 2. Save a backup copy of this file somewhere in case you make a mistake and you need to revert your changes.
> 3. Scroll down to the Mac (“maci64”) section of this file, beginning around line 120.
> 4. Replace all instances of 10.7 with 10.8; there are four of these in all (a fifth may be found in comments only)
> 5. Save the file, then execute the following command in the MATLAB Command Window:
>
> mex -setup
>
> Please note that this workaround links MEX files with a different SDK
>   than with which MATLAB was tested. Although there are no known
>   compatibility issues, support may be limited.